NextJs 14 can't use getStaticProps anymore what i should use in my code
Next 14 can't use getStaticProps I want to send props to my Home page for loop my data what should I do.
import { stripe } from "./utils/stripe";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const inventory = await stripe.products.list({
    limit: 8,
  });
  return {
    props: {
      products: inventory
    }
  }
}


export default function Home({ products }) {
  console.log(products);

  return (
    <div>
        Test
    </div>
  );
}

I want to send my return props to home page for loop data.
